# Controlling the callback flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've the below Node.js code.

**index.js**

```
"use strict";
// Close dialog with the user, reporting fulfillmentState of Failed or Fulfilled

var service = require("./service.js");

function dispatch() {
  const op = service.createIncident("enterpriseID", "shortDesc", function(
    incidentNo
  ) {
    if (incidentNo) {
      console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
      var msg = "Thank you! Your  Number is " + incidentNo;
      console.log("end of flow");
    } else {
      console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
      msg = "Err";
      console.log("end of flow");
    }
  });
  console.log("done");
}

dispatch();
```

and here is my service.js

```
var request = require("request-promise");
var servicenow = require("./configfile.json");

var snowURL = servicenow.url;
var snowUsername = servicenow.username;
var snowPassword = servicenow.password;
var ticketNo = "00000";

console.log(
  "Service Now URL:" +
    snowURL +
    " Username:" +
    snowUsername +
    " Password:" +
    snowPassword
);

module.exports = {
  createIncident: function(caller_id, short_description, callback) {
    var snowdetails = {
      uri: snowURL,
      json: {
        short_description: short_description
      },
      method: "POST",
      auth: {
        username: snowUsername,
        password: snowPassword
      }
    };

    request(snowdetails)
      .then(function(body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
        ticketNo = data.result.number;
        console.log("Service Now Incident No:" + ticketNo);
        callback(ticketNo);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```

when I run this program, I get the output as

```
Service Now URL:myUrl 
Username:myUserName Password:myPassword
done
Service Now Incident No:INC0010107
Index.js ServiceNow Incident:INC0010107
end of flow
```

but as per the flow, I need the output as.

```
Service Now URL:myUrl
Username:myUserName Password:myPassword
Service Now Incident No:INC0010107
Index.js ServiceNow Incident:INC0010107
end of flow
done
```

I know that this is related to callbacks and promises, but not sire of how to do it. please help me on what should I change to get the output as in flow (`done` being printed  as the last thing)

Comment: Check out the `promise` module in npm.

Answer (score 0):

The console statement that prints *done* is not in the callback, so is executed right after *service.createIncident* has been called.

It's easy to fix, simply move the log statement to the callback:

```
function dispatch() {
    const op = service.createIncident("enterpriseID", "shortDesc",
        function (incidentNo) {
            if (incidentNo) {
                console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
                var msg = "Thank you! Your  Number is " + incidentNo;
                console.log("end of flow");
            } else {
                console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
                msg = "Err";
                console.log("end of flow");
            }
            console.log("done");
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is return the promise that is created within 
`createIncident`. By doing this, there's no need to pass a callback to `createIncident` and you can return the `ticketNo` directly from the returned promise and it will propagate down the promise chain.

Do note that, by attaching a `catch` handler at this point, in case of an error, the chain will still continue.

```
createIncident: function (caller_id, short_description/*, callback*/) {
                                                  // ^ no need for callback with promises
  var snowdetails = {
    // ...
  };

  return request(snowdetails)
  // ^ return here
    .then(function (body) {
      var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
      ticketNo = data.result.number;
      console.log("Service Now Incident No:" + ticketNo);
      return ticketNo; // <-- propagate ticketNo through the promise chain
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

As far as `dispatch`, you can now chain the call to `service.createIncident` and receive the `ticketNo` as `incidentNo` in the `then` callback:

```
function dispatch() {
  return service.createIncident("enterpriseID", "shortDesc")
    .then(function (incidentNo) {
      if (incidentNo) {
        console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
        var msg = "Thank you! Your  Number is " + incidentNo;
        console.log("end of flow");
      } else {
        console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
        msg = "Err";
        console.log("end of flow");
      }
    });
}

dispatch()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("done");
  })
```